# number of different levels of categorical variable within time window, by id

Tags: stata

Here's the problem I'm trying to solve

I have data that look like

```
id time pcode
1  1    1    
1  2    1    
1  3    1    
1  4    2    
1  5    4    
1  6    1
```

(I actually have multiple id's; panels aren't strongly balanced, in fact there may be gaps, but that's a complication I'll save for later)

`pcode` is a categorical variable (think product codes) with potentially many (anywhere between 50 and 500) levels.

I am trying to generate variables with **the number of the unique levels of `pcode` within a time window**. For example, for windows of two and three periods, I'd like to generate tow variables, `ncode2` and `ncode3` respectively, that looked like

```
id time pcode ncode2 ncode3
1  1    1     1      2
1  2    1     2      3
1  3    1     2      3
1  4    2     2      2
1  5    4     1      1
1  6    1     .      .
```

To be sure: when `time=1`, `ncode2` looks at times 2 and 3; there's only one level of `pcode` at times 2 and 3 (which is 1), so `ncode2=1`. When `time=2`, `ncode2` looks at times 3 and 4, finds the unique values 1 and 2, and records `ncode2=2`. And so on.

I am not too concerned about what happens when you start reaching the end of the panel; here, I assigned values to `ncode2` and `ncode3` so long as there was one period ahead to look at, and missing if not.

Comment: I see no attempt at code here. In many corners of this forum, there would be a vote to close given that.

Comment: you mean vote down, not close down https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions

Comment: No; I meant what I said "vote to close". Few people have the reputation to close unilaterally.

Comment: right -- and I meant one shouldn't vote to close based on what you said, at least not according to the link I posted.

Comment: I thought your question was worth answering, but there are many discussions on Meta centred on views that questions without code are outside the terms of the forum as (e.g.) showing no research effort or unclear what you're asking (i.e. we can't comment on code you don't show).

Comment: yes, I know there are discussions, but the matter of fact is, one shouldn't vote to close a question just because OP didn't post code. you thought the question was worth answering partially because it was a clear, well-posed question. that's a start. and that's much better than 90% of stata-related questions on statalist, or any other forum, this one included.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd create variables containing the next value in the panel, the one after that, and so forth.

Then apply the `egen` function `rownvals()` in the package `egenmore`, which must be installed using `ssc`.

```
. clear 

. input id time pcode

             id       time      pcode
1. 1  1    1    
2. 1  2    1    
3. 1  3    1    
4. 1  4    2    
5. 1  5    4    
6. 1  6    1    
7. 2  4    3
8. 2  5    4
9. 2  6    1
10. end 

. tsset id time 
   panel variable:  id (unbalanced)
    time variable:  time, 1 to 6
            delta:  1 unit

. gen pcode1 = F.pcode
(2 missing values generated)

. gen pcode2 = F2.pcode
(4 missing values generated)

 . gen pcode3 = F3.pcode 
 (6 missing values generated)

. egen distinct2 = rownvals(pcode1 pcode2) 

. egen distinct3 = rownvals(pcode1 pcode2 pcode3) 

. list, sepby(id) 

        +--------------------------------------------------------------------+
        | id   time   pcode   pcode1   pcode2   pcode3   distin~2   distin~3 |
        |--------------------------------------------------------------------|
     1. |  1      1       1        1        1        2          1          2 |
     2. |  1      2       1        1        2        4          2          3 |
     3. |  1      3       1        2        4        1          2          3 |
     4. |  1      4       2        4        1        .          2          2 |
     5. |  1      5       4        1        .        .          1          1 |
     6. |  1      6       1        .        .        .          0          0 |
        |--------------------------------------------------------------------|
     7. |  2      4       3        4        1        .          2          2 |
     8. |  2      5       4        1        .        .          1          1 |
     9. |  2      6       1        .        .        .          0          0 |
        +--------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

For principles, related technique is discussed at some length in [Distinct observations](http://www.stata-journal.com/sjpdf.html?articlenum=dm0042) (which urges use of the term "distinct", not "unique") and in [Rowwise](http://www.stata-journal.com/sjpdf.html?articlenum=pr0046).

The `egen` function used here pivots on using the Mata function `uniqrows()` to reduce a vector to a set of distinct values each occurring just once.